# Where is the output of the regStats() function in gem5 stored?

Tags: gem5

Does the regStats() function record every tick? If so, where is the recorded data output? I only saw the configuration information of all aspects of gem5 in stats.txt.

Comment: Did you dump the statistics? I think you need an explicit dump to dump to a file.

Comment: Do you mean that regStat() counts every tick, but I need to specify which file to dump to?

Comment: I don't think it counts every tick, but you need to call `Dump()` to get output from it. You could call it every tick I think.

Comment: `Dump` dumps the current state, otherwise you will have only a single `Dump` at the end of the simulation.

Comment: Is there a more detailed introduction about dump()? Where should I use this function? What is the format of this function? thank you very much

Comment: Unfortunately the [docs](https://www.gem5.org/documentation/general_docs/statistics/api) seem sparse, and just mention it's existence. There's an example in a `c` program at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23841867/gem5-cache-statistics-reset-and-dump, though it's also short.

Comment: If you search *dump* at https://www.gem5.org/documentation/learning_gem5/part1/gem5_stats/ you will see a general explanation, but again, documentation seems to be a bit lacking.

Comment: From what I can tell, you need to exit your simulation loop and call Dump every time you want to dump it, so it's completely manual.